# Filter a HTML Table using <select>

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, smarty

I'm locked, i try to filter a html table when i change the dropdown value.
I want to refresh the table after select the value.

I work on a prestashop module, he use Smarty for the templating.

Example :

```
<tr>
   <select name="valueType" id="select">
     <option value="all" selected="selected" disabled>Select type of document</option>
     <option value="0">Invoice 1</option>
     <option value="1">Invoice 2</option>
     <option value="3">Invoice 3</option>
   </select>
   <a type="button" class="btn" href="{$link->getModuleLink('invoice', 'myinvoices', array(), true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">Voir tout</a>
</tr>
```

```
<tbody>
   {if isset($invoices) && $invoices}
   {foreach from=$invoices item=invoice}
   <tr>
       <td><a class="dl" href="{$invoice.link}" title="{l s='Download the invoice number'    mod='aechistoryinvoice'} {$invoice.invoice_number}"><i class="icon-file-pdf-o left"></i> {l s='Download' mod='aechistoryinvoice'}</a></td>
       <td class="align-center">{$invoice.invoice_number}</td>
       <td class="align-center">{$invoice.invoice_date}</td>
       <td class="align-right"><strong>{$invoice.total_amount_tax_excl}</strong></td>
       <td class="align-right">{$invoice.total_amount_tax_incl}</td>
       <td class="align-right">{$invoice.type_document}</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}  
    {else}     
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">{l s='No data yet' mod='invoice'}</td>
    </tr>
  {/if}
</tbody>
```

I've retrieve on the browser console the value when i select what i want. For this i've use :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
   })
</script>
```

I don't know, how can i do the filter..

Thanx

Comment: Very simply put you need to use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to 1. send the selected value to the server 2. load the filtered table from PHP/Smarty 3. update the table by replacing it with the newly loaded one

Comment: Note that if you always output the entire table in your template code, you can then iterate over its rows and show hide them based on the selection. No fetch needed.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/d60kj4qu/

Comment: Ok it's good, i've config for the module. Thank you a lot !